# MongoDB atlas trigger find return 50k documents while the count is 63k

Tags: mongodb, triggers, mongodb-atlas

I am using atlas trigger in atlas, when I am fetching records it is returning only 50k records white the total data is 63k. Is there any limit for data fetching on atlas trigger.

```
const docs = await collection1.find().sort({ "_id" : -1}).toArray();
const count = await collection1.count({});
console.log('count = ',count);
console.log('found records un-processed', docs.length);

count =  63101
found records un-processed 50000
> result: 
{
  "$undefined": true
}
> result (JavaScript): 
EJSON.parse('{"$undefined":true}')
```

This is the result I get when I ran the trigger. Need help

Answer (score 0):

See [documentation of count](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/count/)

> Avoid using the `count` and its wrapper methods without a query predicate (note: `db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount()` does not take a query predicate) since without the query predicate, these operations return results based on the collection's metadata, which may result in an approximate count. In particular,
>
> - On a sharded cluster, the resulting count will not correctly filter out orphaned documents.
> - After an unclean shutdown, the count may be incorrect.

Use `db.collection.countDocuments()` or `db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount()`, depending on your needs

Comment: TypeError: 'countDocuments' is not a function. TypeError: 'estimatedDocumentCount' is not a function.
My question is different you answering different. Please see the question again.